# Nginx Php Upload too slow ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, pagespeed

My cloud runs ubuntu 16.04 on Digitalocean.
I have installed custom build of nginx (with ngx_pagespeed module) via Auto Installing script from the tutorial here: 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

The fileupload speed is too slow to the server, trying to upload 1 Mb file (sql file) to phpmyadmin and it's taking too long.

My nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
#include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
#    include       mime.types;
#    default_type  application/octet-stream;

client_max_body_size 100M;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;


#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;


server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
pagespeed on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
add_header "" "";
}
location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
root   html;
index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root   html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}



# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

include /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My website conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.blah.com;
        root /home/website/blah/public;
        index index.php;

    #   pagespeed on;
    #pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

    # Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed handler
    # and no extraneous headers get set.
    #location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
        #  add_header "" "";
    #}
    #location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
    #location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8909;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Please Help...

Comment: well - have you checked that against your local upload rate?

Comment: how to check that?? please mention that..

Comment: i have just shifted from amazon ec2 to digitalocean it was fine on ec2

Comment: @AnandSiddharth You can check your internet's D/U speed www.speedtest.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While performing automated install as documented in https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source it asks for extra arguments for nginx before building it. I had to provide following necessary arguments:

```
--add-module=/home/website/ngx_pagespeed-latest-stable --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads
```

It worked!